Uploading multiple images but uploading another image the old one is deleted from input
To upload multiple images am using this code


$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#images").on("change", function (e) {
            var files = e.target.files,
                selectedfile,
                selectedfiles = [];

            filesLength = files.length;

            var image_el = $('#showImages');
            image_el.removeClass('d-none');
            image_el.addClass('row');

            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                selectedfile = files[i]
                
                selectedfiles.push(selectedfile)

                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = (function (e) {  
                    var _div = "<div class=\"col-md-3 position-relative pip\">";
                    _div += "<img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" style=\"height: 120px; width: 100%; display: block;\">";
                    _div += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"position-absolute top-0 end-0 remove_image\" role=\"" + selectedfile.name + "\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></a>";
                    _div += "</div>";
                    image_el.append(_div);
                    
                    $(".remove_image").on("click", function (e) {
                        var pips = $('.pip').toArray();
                        var $selectedPip = $(this).parent('.pip');
                        var index = pips.indexOf($selectedPip[0]);
            
                        var dt = new DataTransfer();
                        var files = $("#images")[0].files;
            
                        for (var fileIdx = 0; fileIdx < files.length; fileIdx++) {
                            if (fileIdx !== index) {
                                dt.items.add(files[fileIdx]);
                            }
                        }
            
                        $("#images")[0].files = dt.files;
            
                        $selectedPip.remove();
                    });
                });
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(selectedfile);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
    }
});



The upload is working fine but the problem is when i want to add another image, the other uploaded are deleted when I submit the form
Could someone please provide some resources or a code snippet? but the input is not keeping the previous loaded images.
